Send email with onEdit simple trigger is not working
The send email in onEdit function is not working.

When I tried using only the code for sending an email, it worked, but not in the onEdit function.
Here's the sample code. The goal is everytime the user check the box, it will send an email to the recipient.
function onEdit(e) {
    var range = e.range;
    var col = range.getColumn();
    var row = range.getRow();
    var edited_value = e.value();
    var ss = e.range.getSheet();

    if (col == 12 && edited_value == "TRUE") {
        var message = "This is a test of HTML <br><br> Line two";

        var recipientsTO = "cedric@example.com" + "," + "nerlyn@example.com";
        var recipientsCC = "john@example.com";
        var Subject = "Poynt Received New Feedback ";
        var html = message;

        GmailApp.sendEmail({
            to: recipientsTO,
            cc: recipientsCC,
            subject: Subject,
            htmlBody: html
        });
    }
}


Make it installable
function onMyEdit(e) {
    var sh = e.range.getSheet();
    if (sh.getName() == "Your sheet name" && e.range.columnstart == 12 && e.value == "TRUE") {
        var message = "This is a test of HTML <br><br> Line two";
        var recipientsTO = "cedric@example.com" + "," + "nerlyn@example.com";
        var recipientsCC = "john@example.com";
        var subject = "Poynt Received New Feedback ";
        var html = message;
        GmailApp.sendEmail(recipientsTO,subject,"",{htmlBody: html,cc:recipientsCC});
    }
}


The reason your script is erroring is that e.value isn't a function, it's a field. Removing the parentheses correctly accesses the new value.
function onEdit(e) {
    var range = e.range;
    var col = range.getColumn();
    var row = range.getRow();
    var edited_value = e.value;


    if (col == 12 && edited_value == "TRUE") {
        var message = "This is a test of HTML <br><br> Line two";

        var recipientsTO = "cedric@example.com" + "," + "nerlyn@example.com";
        var recipientsCC = "john@example.com";
        var Subject = "Poynt Received New Feedback ";
        var html = message;

        GmailApp.sendEmail({
            to: recipientsTO,
            cc: recipientsCC,
            subject: Subject,
            htmlBody: html
        });
    }
}

What you will find after correcting this, however, is that simple triggers (like onEdit) have several additional restrictions on them, which prevent you from using services that require authorization, which Gmail is. To get around this, you can check out these instructions

I already removed the parentheses but still not working.

Then I'd follow the link @smallpepperz provided to resolve the authorization issues you're likely facing.

Check your executions log, is it saying something like "TypeError: e.value is not a function" ?
I think you should change
var edited_value = e.value();

to
var edited_value = e.value;


I already removed the parentheses but still not working.
